# Cannot get the types right for SVG commponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component where i import svgs as `ReactComponent`, In that component i am mapping the svgs to a `key` string that will return the correct svg.

Everything works the problem I am having is a problem with Typescripts. import React, { SVGProps, FC } from "react";

```
import { ReactComponent as FacebookLogo } from "../../images/icon-facebook.svg";
import { ReactComponent as TwitterLogo } from "../../images/icon-twitter.svg";
import { ReactComponent as InstagramLogo } from "../../images/icon-instagram.svg";
import { ReactComponent as YoutubeLogo } from "../../images/icon-youtube.svg";
import { ReactComponent as ArrowUp } from "../../images/icon-up.svg";
import { ReactComponent as ArrowDown } from "../../images/icon-down.svg";

type logoMapType = { [key: string]: FC<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>> };

const logoTypesMap: logoMapType = {
  facebookLogo: FacebookLogo,
  twitterLogo: TwitterLogo,
  instagramLogo: InstagramLogo,
  youtubeLogo: YoutubeLogo,
  arrowUp: ArrowUp,
  arrowDown: ArrowDown,
};

const SvgExporter = (logoName: string) => {
  let Logo = logoTypesMap[logoName];
  return <Logo />;
};

export default SvgExporter;
```

When i am using my `SvgExporter` in one of my components i am getting this type error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ logoName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

      <div className="flex justify-center flex-1 w-[55px] ">
        <SvgExporter logoName={card.icon} />
      </div>
```

`card.icon` is a string. So when i am passing a string into `SvgExporter` that matches the `logoTypesMap` and returns the correct svg.

But i am struggling to understand the types error message.

When i try to type `SvgExporter` function param to `{ logoName: string }` i get this error:

`TS2538: Type '{ logoName: string; }' cannot be used as an index type.`

Comment: Revisit how to define props for components. First parameter is supposed to be an object.

Comment: @vr
I mean it can be an object only if you destructure the props object. Dont think you have to do it but yes you can, i actually destructured `logoName` from props object but i was messing around so much i forgot to put it back. even if i do this:

`const SvgExporter = ({ logoName }: string) => {// function code}` i get this error:
`TS2322: Type '{ logoName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Comment: Change the string type to the correct object type then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter should be an object type. Then you can destructure it:

```
const SvgExporter = ({ logoName }: { logoName: string }) => {
  let Logo = logoTypesMap[logoName];
  return <Logo />;
};
```

Comment: thx this is what i have actually ended up with